# PowerPlatform Build Tools Azure DevOps Deployment Settings File

Tags: powerapps, alm, power-platform

My team is trying to figure out ALM for our PowerApps. We have been able to build and deploy the solution without using deployment settings but are now trying to map our environment variables and connection references. We have encountered a roadblock the last few weeks and haven't been able to get passed it. We've verified our connection IDs, ensured they are shared to our service principle. We keep getting this error with little detail on what is going on. Any ideas for our team to try?

We thought the issue was on our shared office 365 connector or approval connector. The other connector is a little more straightforward with an Azure connection. I'm not sure if anyone else has had similar issues?

[image]